# Why when using the key "p" to give Acceleration power to the spaceships it's doing anything?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The spaceships speed is the same. What i want to make is to give the spaceships Acceleration effect. So each time i press the key p the spaceships will get Acceleration.

It's getting to the code part when i click the p key i used breakpoint. But it's not effecting the spaceships when the game is running.

Each spaceship have Rigidbody component and Use Gravity is set to false and Is isKinematic set to true.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Control : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int rotationSpeed = 75;
    public int movementspeed = 10;
    public int thrust = 10;

    bool isPKeyDown = false;
    float acceleration = .0f;

    Vector3 previousPosition = Vector3.zero;

    Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Debug.Log("Acc Speed: " + thrust);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        var v3 = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f);
        transform.Rotate(v3 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("p"))
        {
            isPKeyDown = Input.GetKey("p");
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(previousPosition, transform.position);
            acceleration = distance / Mathf.Pow(Time.deltaTime, 2);

            previousPosition = transform.position;
            _rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(0f, 0f, thrust, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (isPKeyDown)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 100, 200, 200), "Acc Speed: " + acceleration);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note on your code, you are calculating the velocity when you could simply use `acceleration = _rigidbody.velocity.magnitude` for the accurate speed details, as your code will not take collisions into consideration. (slightly bumping of a collider will cause the actual speed to be different than the calculated value, obviously)

Answer (score 1):

If the `RigidBody` is set to `isKinematic`, you have to change its `transform.position` directly, the various `AddForce` methods won't work (they work only if it's not `isKinematic`).

Even if you change directly the `velocity` propriety of the rigid body, it won't move since all physics is disabled on such objects.